# Generate both access and refresh tokens in Laravel login

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-passport, laravel-api

Im trying to implement authentication in laravel using passport.
I need to create a New accessToken and refreshToken once the user logs in.
Now, following Laravel's documentation, it can be donde like this:

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
 
   $response = Http::asForm()->post('http://passport-app.test/oauth/token', [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'username' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
        'password' => 'my-password',
        'scope' => '',
    ]);
     
    return $response->json();
```

The workaround here would be to make an API endpoint that would basically take the user's credentials and post them with the other required data to the above endpoint.

Is it OK to call a route of my own API from another route or my API?. It feels like it should be a better way to do this. Can someone point me to that way if it exists or if there is a better implementation?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenID-Connect, you should always ask for the **openid** scope.

To get a refresh token, you also need to ask for the **offline_access** scope.

Like

```
 'scope' => 'openid offline_access',
```